# How can I get video quality from Android Youtube API?

Tags: android, youtube-api, resolution, android-youtube-api

I have implemented the YouTube fragment and what I wanna do next is to get the video quality from YouTube Android API. But I didn't find any solution in API. I only want to get the video quality, I don't need to modify it. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

YouTube Android native api not providing video Quality functions. Although you can get video Quality using Iframe of YouTube api. You have to implement webview with Iframe. [youtube Iframe api link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Playback_quality)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! Is it possible that I put my YouTube fragment into the webview iframe or something like that? I really don't want to restart my project.